# expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘=’ token

Tags: c

I'm having trouble with this line:

`ut_slot = malloc(tab_size * sizeof ut_slot_t);`

These are the variables which are defined in the header file:

`typedef struct _ut_slot {
...
...
} ut_slot_t, *ut_slot;`

error is written in title, any help?

Comment: you never actually declared ut_slot as a variable, you just declared it as a pointer type in that typedef

Comment: that was the whole problem.. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
ut_slot = malloc(tab_size * sizeof ut_slot_t);
```

to

```
ut_slot_t *ut_slot = malloc(tab_size * sizeof *ut_slot);
```

and remove `ut_slot` from the typedef:

```
typedef struct _ut_slot {
...
...
} ut_slot_t;
```

Comment: (+1) This is the better answer. I had not noticed the missing/wrong variable declaration.

Answer (score 6):

If `ut_slot_t` is a type then you have to put it in parentheses:

```
 ut_slot = malloc(tab_size * sizeof(ut_slot_t));
```

*Edit:* The above is correct (I think!), but only one part of the problem. The other answer
solves it completely.

Comment: You did beat me to it. +1

Comment: @xd6_: The syntax of `sizeof` is either `sizeof expression` or `sizeof ( type-name )`

Comment: @xd6_: Yes, `sizeof expression` doesn't need parentheses. I was about to add that info, but the other answer already says it.